# JTextField width according to max input, calculating string width

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I would like to have a TextField which shows by its width the maximum of allowed
input characters.
I used Font.getStringBounds to calculate the width of the maximum length.
But to my surprise the resulting width in the example looks like omitting a
complete character!

- Using FontMetrics.stringWidth supplies the same width value.
- Creating the textField just using the JTextField(int columns) constructor gave
  a better result, but the field is still too small.

What is missing?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InputWidthTextField extends JFrame {

  public InputWidthTextField() {
    setSize(250, 230);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 60, 20));
    Font font= new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12);
    int max= 4;
    JLabel lb= new JLabel("Enter up to "+max+" characters:");
    add(lb);
    MaxInputWidthTextField tf= new MaxInputWidthTextField(font, max);
    add(tf);
    setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(InputWidthTextField::new);
  }


  class MaxInputWidthTextField extends JTextField {
    public MaxInputWidthTextField(Font font, int maxCount) {
      super();
      if (font==null)
        font= getFont();
      else
        setFont(font);
      FontMetrics fm= getFontMetrics(font);
      FontRenderContext frc= fm.getFontRenderContext();
      String buf= "8".repeat(maxCount);
      Rectangle2D rect= font.getStringBounds(buf, frc);
      Dimension dim= new Dimension((int)rect.getWidth(), (int)rect.getHeight());
      setPreferredSize(dim);
      System.out.println((int)rect.getWidth()+", "+(int)rect.getHeight());
      System.out.println(fm.stringWidth(buf));
      System.out.println(getGraphics());
    }    
  }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using [`public JTextField​(int columns)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#%3Cinit%3E(int))?

Comment: @MadProgrammer As I have written: It gives a better, but not satisfying result. The textfield will be too small to completely take in max characters without scrolling.

Comment: @Jörg *Creating the textField just using the JTextField(int columns) constructor gave a better result, but the field is still too small.* - The preferred size should be large enough to hold "W" characters. Must admit if I enter 4 "W" characters it does get truncated. But for all other combinations it works fine for me. Since I doubt you would ever enter 4 "W" characters this constructor should work fine. Post your [mre] with the data used to test this constructor and scrolling is required for 4 characters.

Comment: @Jörg Really, because when I compare your attempt to the default implementation, I'd prefer the default implementation

Comment: @Camickr Since I set the TextField to MONOSPACED font, any character(s) should be good for testing. For the requested MRP, just replace `MaxInputWidthTextField tf= new ...` by the ordinary `JTextField tf= new JTextField(n)`, set the font to the field and then enter n characters. The same "truncation" will happen that you already observed.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The good thing with the default implementation is that the amount which will become hidden seems to be constant and not vary with max. So I could get the PreferredSize and enlarge it according to font size. Still, I wonder that calculating a string width is that difficult that it becomes inexact.

Comment: @Jörg I think the documentation states it pretty well *"The meaning of what a column is can be considered a fairly weak notion for some fonts"* - So, at the very best, it's a "guestimation".  While a fixed width font will generally give the best results, a variable width font is going to screw with you.  You also need to take into consideration the `insets` been applied to the textfield by the L&F as well.  Take a look at the default implementation of `JTextField#getPreferredSize` (posted below), this will give you an idea of how the Swing team attempted to solve this issue

Comment: (1-) @Jörg, I don't understand the point of your last comment to me. I already stated that I did test. I did NOT test every possible combination of 4 characters. The ONLY combination that didn't work for me was "WWWW". If this is an issue for you then you need to solve the problem on your own. Otherwise the default size calculation should work for any other combination that you might use. That is why I specifically asked your what test characters YOU used!!! That is why you post an MRE so we don't have to guess! Voted to close since details have NOT be included even after prompting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not even going to try and figure out all the things that are wrong with your code, instead, I'm going to demonstrate what you should be doing instead.

Take a look at [`public JTextField​(int columns)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#%3Cinit%3E(int))

> **JTextField**
>
> ```
> public JTextField​(int columns)
> ```
>
> Constructs a new empty
> TextField with the specified number of columns. A default model is
> created and the initial string is set to null. 
> *Parameters: columns -*
> the number of columns to use to calculate the preferred width; if
> columns is set to zero, the preferred width will be whatever naturally
> results from the component implementation

So, if we do a side by side comparison, this is what we get (your field is on the bottom)

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(new JTextField(8), gbc);
            add(new MaxInputWidthTextField(null, 8), gbc);
        }

    }

    class MaxInputWidthTextField extends JTextField {

        public MaxInputWidthTextField(Font font, int maxCount) {
            super();
            if (font == null) {
                font = getFont();
            } else {
                setFont(font);
            }
            FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(font);
            FontRenderContext frc = fm.getFontRenderContext();
            String buf = "8".repeat(maxCount);
            Rectangle2D rect = font.getStringBounds(buf, frc);
            Dimension dim = new Dimension((int) rect.getWidth(), (int) rect.getHeight());
            setPreferredSize(dim);
        }
    }
}
```

What I do recommend is having a look at the pre-existing implementation

The `JTextField#getPreferredSize` implementation looks like...

```
/**
 * Returns the column width.
 * The meaning of what a column is can be considered a fairly weak
 * notion for some fonts.  This method is used to define the width
 * of a column.  By default this is defined to be the width of the
 * character <em>m</em> for the font used.  This method can be
 * redefined to be some alternative amount
 *
 * @return the column width &gt;= 1
 */
protected int getColumnWidth() {
    if (columnWidth == 0) {
        FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        columnWidth = metrics.charWidth('m');
    }
    return columnWidth;
}

/**
 * Returns the preferred size <code>Dimensions</code> needed for this
 * <code>TextField</code>.  If a non-zero number of columns has been
 * set, the width is set to the columns multiplied by
 * the column width.
 *
 * @return the dimension of this textfield
 */
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
    if (columns != 0) {
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        size.width = columns * getColumnWidth() +
            insets.left + insets.right;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Instead of "setting" the preferred size, I would "consider" overriding the `getPreferredSize` and injecting your "custom" workflow into instead

## Further experimentation...

So, I did a really quick test...

```
Font monoFont = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 13);
JTextField field = new JTextField();
field.setFont(monoFont);
FontMetrics metrics = field.getFontMetrics(getFont());
for (int i = 32; i < 127; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + ((char) i) + " = " + metrics.charWidth((char)i));
}
```

And found that every character is `8` points wide.  Where as the default font uses the character `m` which is (in my testing) 12 points wide.

So, this got me to thinking, the really problem isn't that the `getPreferredSize` is wrong, it's that we actually need to "pad" the result of `getColumnWidth`, for example...

```
public class MaxInputWidthTextField extends JTextField {

    public MaxInputWidthTextField(Font font, int maxCount) {
        super(maxCount);
        setFont(font);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getColumnWidth() {
        return super.getColumnWidth() + 1;
    }
}
```

which can generate something like...

[image: Simple As]

It's just enough to add a little white space at the trailing end of the text field and you don't need to jump through a lot of hopes to make it work.

### Runnable example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            Font monoFont = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 13);

            add(new JTextField(8), gbc);
            add(new MaxInputWidthTextField(monoFont, 8), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class MaxInputWidthTextField extends JTextField {

        public MaxInputWidthTextField(Font font, int maxCount) {
            super(maxCount);
            setFont(font);
        }

        @Override
        protected int getColumnWidth() {
            return super.getColumnWidth() + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code and explanation. Using a maxCount parameter, as I did, makes it in my view mandatory to work with a monospaced font. - I will check tomorrow what I can make of your getPreferredSize suggestion. For now I can't keep my eyes open.

Answer (score 0):

@Camickr
Rob, you seem to have been very strict yesterday. ;-)
But surely, not understanding is also on my side. For when I tell you that in a monospaced font both "W" and "i" have the same width, this will certainly be nothing new to you. So I don't understand why you are asking me for an MRE or why only "WWWW" didn't work for you. I can only imagine, you didn't use a monospace font,
but this is a sine qua non when calculating the maximum possible width beforehand, given a maximum character count, for any string the user will enter.
I hope, we don't see different things on our screens due to resolution or scaling differences. So I send a picture of how it looks like at my site. Whenever I enter the last character in one of the textfields, the whole string is shifted to the left, so that the first character gets partly hidden. Hence in my example the zero is always cut. You may deem this to be acceptable, but I would prefer to have each character fully visible.
[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FieldWidthTest extends JFrame {

  public FieldWidthTest() {
    setSize(250, 230);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    Font font= new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12);
    int max= 4;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
      JPanel p= new JPanel();
      JTextField tf= new JTextField(max++);
      tf.setFont(font);
      p.add(tf);
      add(p);
    }
    setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(FieldWidthTest::new);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@MadProgrammer
Overriding `getPreferredSize()`, as you suggested, worked well; but using `setPreferredSize()` also did the job and saves the overriding.
It was an error not to create and set a monospaced font in case the paramter was null. The solution, however, was to add 2 to the dimension's width, which worked for all font sizes. Camickr would call this justifiably "using magic numbers", but I don't know where to get this number from.
Thanks to all.

```
  class MaxInputWidthTextField extends JTextField {
    public MaxInputWidthTextField(Font monoFont, int maxCount) {
      super();
      if (monoFont==null) monoFont= new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 13);
      setFont(monoFont);
      FontMetrics fm= getFontMetrics(monoFont);
      FontRenderContext frc= fm.getFontRenderContext();
      String buf= "8".repeat(maxCount);
      Rectangle2D rect= monoFont.getStringBounds(buf, frc);
//      Insets insets= getMargin(); // Parameters are all 0.
      Insets insets= getInsets();
      int iWidth= insets.left + (int)rect.getWidth() + insets.right +2;
      int iHeight= insets.top + (int)rect.getHeight() + insets.bottom;
      Dimension dim= new Dimension(iWidth, iHeight);
      setPreferredSize(dim);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, MadProgrammer, I didn't want to upset you. On the contray I always appreciated your valueable advice. But you yourself wrote of "injecting your 'custom' workflow". I am very well aware not to follow the long tested and established way of the swing engineers. But the special case of a monospaced font is a less intricate situation. I wrote that I first followed your suggestion and overrode ´getPreferredSize´, but still I had to insert my "magic number" to get the desired result. You will certainly have good reasons why overriding `getPreferredSize` is far better than --> tbc

Comment: I'm just highlighting the short comings of `setPreferredSize` ;)

Comment: `setPreferredSize`. If you are willing to spend two more minutes, please tell me about that.

Comment: Just as I said, any one can come along and call `setPreferredSize` and ruin all your hard work - generally speaking, it's "recommended" (and I use the term losly) to avoid using `setPreferredSize`, size you're already extending from `JTextField` so you can restrict it's horizontal size, why not override the method best suited for the job - this is just my opinion, but I've seen people destroy perfectly working code by calling `setPreferredSize` :P

Comment: There's also an "opinion" that `setPreferredSize` should never have been `public` and is actually a design flaw ;)

Comment: I fully understand to better rely on a pre-existing implementation. But I don't see the shortcomings of `setPreferredSize` yet. Can you give me some hints, please?

Comment: Obviously you are typing much quicker than I do. - But I think I now got your point. Thank you very much.

Comment: `MaxInputWidthTextField textField = new MaxInputWidthTextField(...);` `textField.setPreferredSize(1000, 1000);` <- Just undid all your work

Comment: Yes, that makes it very clear!

Comment: Check my update - `getColumnWidth` is actually a MUCH better candidate for overriding in this particular edge case

Comment: Thanks again for your work. But my idea was to show the user, how much space/characters are left for input. Thus an extra blank would break the idea.

Comment: The "extra blank" isn't enough, generally to be a "full" character, but instead, just enough to stop the caret from nudging over the edge of the viewable space ;)